# Content Security Policy : HTTP vs HTTPS on connect-src 'self'

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, content-security-policy

I'm looking at a site (**https**://www.somestore.com) where an XHR/ajax request to **http**://www.somestore.com is getting blocked by the Content Security Policy. Note that the site operates under HTTPS and the ajax request is over HTTP.

This site's CSP policy lists `self` and the store's domain name without the protocol type:

```
connect-src 'self' www.somestore.com
```

Chrome is reporting

```
Refused to connect to 'http://www.somestore.com/...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' www.somestore.com.
```

I don't access to the server to run tests, but at a glance, it seems that the directive should not interfere with the ajax request, but CSP seems to distinguishes between HTTP and HTTPS and treat them as different origins. I could not find any info regarding this online.

My hunch is that `www.somestore.com` can be removed from the directive and the ajax should be changed to HTTPS, and this problem would go away. Any idea?

Comment: Why not just change the XHR request to use the https URL instead of the http one? If you try that, does Chrome still report the “Refused to connect” message? And if you paste the http URL into your browser address bar, what happens? Does it redirect to the https URL?

Comment: That's what I'm going to try first. Plus, removing `www.somestore.com` from the directive. I should be able to try this out this week.